# PDFTK cannot be run by www-data

Tags: permissions, php, pdftk

I need to use PDFTK. It works when I use it in terminal as root, but when I try to use it with www-data I'm consistently getting a permission error.

When switching to www-data:

```
sudo -u www-data sh
```

and executing:

```
fpdtk simply.pdf generate_fdf output fields.fdf
```

I get this output:

```
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
simply.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done. Input errors, so no output created.
```

It seems the issue is that permission is denied for www-data user.

How can I change this?

Comment: Why do you think it is a permission problem? pdftk complains about not finding the file. Is the file in your current folder?

Comment: yes you were right, the issue was with just the current folder permission was, which owner is different than www-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the current folder was not owned by www-data.
So be sure that the the owner is the same as the apache user(www-data or daemon)

Comment: what was your solution for that ?

Comment: sudo chown www-data <directory_name>

Answer (score 3):

[This article](https://wilransz.com/pdftk-on-ubuntu-18-04/) saved my life! I has the same error using the pdftk snap.

Simply create a symlink with this command:

```
sudo ln -s /snap/pdftk/current/usr/bin/pdftk /usr/bin/pdftk
```

Comment: Helpful, but the link is dead, so we do not know **why** it works. This is why it should be better to always add the relevant information in the answer...